# Suddenly my wifi adapter WLAN 802.11 N has stopped worked

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, 802.11n

I did not do anything Just first day of week I start my PC and trying to connect to internet and show the message 'No Wi-Fi adapter Found'...

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I just follow the steps and I get it the  solutions. Its save me money and most important time...

[Click on this link ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04?newreg=ae04d2e2563849c08bee304631c6aaf7)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.